# What are Quasi-Periodic Oscilations and how can they be used to determine the mass of black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, accretion-disk

Quasi-Periodic Oscillations (QPOs) are observed in almost all accreting systems and they provide an essential tool to explore accretion flows from compact objects.

But I couldn't understand what actually are the QPOs and how they can be used to determine the mass of black holes?